# Nightwatchjs tab switching in headless mode with chrome does not work

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js, google-chrome-headless

The below test works perfectly fine when running without the headless mode on chrome. Background of the actual click. The click opens a new tab automatically and is a PDF (similar to blob:https://cooldomains.com/alskdjf3sdd) when the tab is opened. For some reason, the headless mode does NOT act the same way as non-headless. Searched all over google, but can't seem to find an answer to this.

```
.click('@printSelected', () => {
            browser
                .pause(TIMEOUT)
                .window_handles(function (result) {
                    var newWin = result.value[1];
                    var mainWin = result.value[0];
                    browser.switchWindow(newWin)
                        .assert.urlContains('blob')
                        .closeWindow(newWin).switchWindow(mainWin);
                })
        });
        "chromeOptions": {
      "args": [
        "window-size=1880,1200",
        "allow-running-insecure-content",
        "headless"
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding:

```
.pause(3000)
```

just before:

```
browser.switchWindow(newWin)
```

The reason I am thinking that headless chrome runs faster.

Comment: I have done that as well. It's using the PDF viewer of Google, which I believe is the problem. The browser knows the new tab is there, just not able to assert anything on the new tab.